# Library issues while compiling IOS application

Tags: c++, ios, linux, opengl-es, raspberry-pi

This is a bit of a complicated issue, so let me provide some background so you know the full extent of the issue here. I am also rather new to this and it has been a learning experience so far, so I apologise if I'm missing something obvious or simple, or if this question is too lengthy and detailed.

I'm trying to compile a IOS application on, and for, a Raspberry PI. The app is a 3d game/game engine named Sauerbraten, that I believe would be wonderful to have on the PI for fun, tinkering, and educational use thanks to its low performance requirements, open source nature, and real time map editing.

It uses SDL and GL 1.x, and I've sucessfully been able to build and run the original source without issue, besides the obvious fact that it runs using software rendering and thus is far too slow to use. Thankfully, someone previously has ported the game to the IPhone, and thus to GLES, so I decided to use that instead of recoding the original version for GLES.

Since I'm still new to this, I decided to try to compile it first and then see what needs to be changed or fixed. This is where the issue is, I've run into several issues immediately. First, it seems to be unable to enter subdirectories, or at least find headers in them. If I try to compile it, I get this:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/cube/Saurbraten/trunk/src $ sudo make
make    -C enet/ all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pi/cube/Saurbraten/trunk/src/enet'
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"libenet\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"libenet\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.3.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"libenet\ 1.3.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"libenet\" -DVERSION=\"1.3.0\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAS_GETHOSTBYADDR_R=1 -DHAS_GETHOSTBYNAME_R=1 -DHAS_POLL=1 -DHAS_FCNTL=1 -DHAS_INET_PTON=1 -DHAS_INET_NTOP=1 -DHAS_MSGHDR_FLAGS=1 -DHAS_SOCKLEN_T=1 -I. -Iinclude    -g -O2 -MT callbacks.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/callbacks.Tpo -c -o callbacks.lo callbacks.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"libenet\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"libenet\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.3.0\" "-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"libenet 1.3.0\"" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"libenet\" -DVERSION=\"1.3.0\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DHAS_GETHOSTBYADDR_R=1 -DHAS_GETHOSTBYNAME_R=1 -DHAS_POLL=1 -DHAS_FCNTL=1 -DHAS_INET_PTON=1 -DHAS_INET_NTOP=1 -DHAS_MSGHDR_FLAGS=1 -DHAS_SOCKLEN_T=1 -I. -Iinclude -g -O2 -MT callbacks.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/callbacks.Tpo -c callbacks.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/callbacks.o
callbacks.c:6:18: fatal error: enet.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [callbacks.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/cube/Saurbraten/trunk/src/enet'
make: *** [libenet] Error 2
pi@raspberrypi ~/cube/Saurbraten/trunk/src $
```

I 'solved' this by just coping the header files from /src/enet/include/enet into /src/enet. Enet then compiles sucessfully, but I think this may be one problem caused by a larger issue that is also responsible for my current problem.

My current problem is when trying to compile the rest of it, I get this:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/cube/Saurbraten/trunk/src $ sudo make
make    -C enet/ all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pi/cube/Saurbraten/trunk/src/enet'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pi/cube/Saurbraten/trunk/src/enet'
g++ -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -fsigned-char -Ishared -Iengine -Ifpsgame -Ienet/include -I/usr/X11R6/include `sdl-config --cflags` -o shared/cube.h.gch.tmp shared/cube.h
shared/cube.h:87:26: fatal error: SDL_opengles.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [shared/cube.h.gch] Error 1
```

I've tried downloading that header and putting it into the /src/shared directory, but then I get this:

```
shared/cube.h:88:29: fatal error: OpenGLES/es1/gl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Even modifying the header so it points to the correct path for gl.h doesn't solve or change the error, so at this point I'm certain the issue must be with the makefile, but I don't know what the issue is seeing as the author has compiled it without trouble. I hope this question isn't too vague, but at this point I'm fresh out of ideas. I've already asked on the Raspberry-PI forums, they recommended installing SDL2, which didn't solve anything, probably since it doesn't use SDL2.

Edit: I forgot to mention what the enviroment is - I'm on Raspbian, effectively debian, using the 'Make' command, no XCode or similar. The source does not have a configure file.

Comment: Rather than changing header files, you should add the paths to the make options

Answer (score 0):

You need to add -Idirectory/to/include when compiling.

A common practice is to add this on the CFLAGS (or CXXFLAGS) because you want to specify the include folders to ALL objects which are going to be compiled .

For your case (considering that src is found in the root of your system):

```
CFLAGS=-I/src/enet/include/enet
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, though this didn't actually solve either of my issues. I figured out a bit of a silly solution on my own. It asked for gl.h at OpenGLES/es1, so I just created that and put gl.h in it. I'm still convinced that something is severely wrong if it keeps acting like this so this tip might be useful later, thank you.